# How to build Qt 5.1 for QNX target (arm)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake, qnx

### new update

I think I should edit the title now.

To make sure I got a clean environment, I

1. download qt5.1.1 src code from qt-prject.
2. export QNX_TARGET, QNX_HOST, AND add QNX_HOST into PATH.
3. then Run the script
   `./configure -opensource -confirm-license -xplatform qnx-armv7le-qcc -v`

so in here, -opensource -confirm-license just avoid the Q&A -v is to show full message.

a lot of error message.

```
Creating qmake...
make: Nothing to be done for `first'.
Running configuration tests...
Determining architecture... ()
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -c -Wno-psabi -lang-c++ -g -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_NO_CLIPBOARD -I../../mkspecs/qnx-armv7le-qcc -I. -I/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include -I/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -o arch.o arch.cpp
Unable to determine architecture!

Could not determine the target architecture!
Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to see the final report.
Determining architecture... ()
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -fPIE  -I../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -o arch.o arch.cpp
g++  -o arch arch.o    { test -n "" && DESTDIR="" || DESTDIR=.; } && test $(gdb --version | sed -e 's,[^0-9]\+\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\).*,\1\2,;q') -gt 72 && gdb --nx --batch --quiet -ex 'set confirm off' -ex "save gdb-index $DESTDIR" -ex quit 'arch' && test -f arch.gdb-index && objcopy --add-section '.gdb_index=arch.gdb-index' --set-section-flags '.gdb_index=readonly' 'arch' 'arch' && rm -f arch.gdb-index || true
Found architecture in binary
CFG_HOST_ARCH="x86_64"
CFG_HOST_CPUFEATURES=" mmx sse sse2"
System architecture: 'unknown'
Host architecture: 'x86_64'
C++11 auto-detection... ()
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -c -Wno-psabi -lang-c++ -O2 -Wc,-std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIE-DQT_NO_CLIPBOARD -I../../../mkspecs/qnx-armv7le-qcc -I. -I/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include -I/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -o c++11.o c++11.cpp
C++11 disabled.
floatmath auto-detection... ()
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -c -Wno-psabi -lang-c++ -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_NO_CLIPBOARD-I../../../mkspecs/qnx-armv7le-qcc -I. -I/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include -I/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -o floatmath.o floatmath.cpp
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -c -Wno-psabi -lang-c++ -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_NO_CLIPBOARD -I../../../mkspecs/qnx-armv7le-qcc -I. -I/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include -I/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -o freetype.o freetype.cpp
FreeType disabled.
STL auto-detection... ()
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -c -Wno-psabi -lang-c++ -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_NO_CLIPBOARD -I../../../mkspecs/qnx-armv7le-qcc -I. -I/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include -I/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -o stltest.o stltest.cpp
STL disabled.
STL functionality check failed! Cannot build Qt with this STL library.
Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to /home/pasadeveloper/qt-everywhere-opensourcesrc-5.1.1/qtbase/configure to see the final report.
```

---

UPDATE:
I am working on QNX for ARM, target is an arm platform device. 
Thing is getting weird. in Env Var, I put

```
$QNX_CONFIGURATION=/etc/qnx
$QNX_JAVAHOME=/opt/qnx650/_jvm
$QNX_TARGET=/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6
$QNX_HOST=/opt/qnx650/host/linux/x86
```

but when I do `qmake qmake.conf` mkspecs/qnx-armv7le-qcc folder
it returns an error message `Project ERROR: QNX_TARGET environment variable not set`

Have no clue what is going on now.

---

not just qmake qmake.conf
I try to build qt 5.1.2 at another host, ubuntu 12.04-64bit. 
also get the same error message.  `Project ERROR: QNX_TARGET environment variable not set`

---

I was working at Qt development under linux(FYI Ubuntu 12.04 -64bits), but I need to compile this program to binary for QNX. 
I install QNX MOmentics IDE which provide QNX-gcc for me. 
but I can't find the qmake-qnx.

Under the QT/gcc_64/mkspecs/qnx-armv7le-qcc, there is a file call qmake.conf. I guess this is where I can generate my qmake-qnx. after I run qmake -o Makefile qmake.conf, there is a Makefile generated.

However, when I run make, error occured.

```
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -lang-c++ -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/armle-v7/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/pasadeveloper/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/pasadeveloper/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/lib -o qmake    -L/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/armle-v7/lib -L/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib -lm -L/home/pasadeveloper/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
```

`cc: no files to process
  make: *** [qmake] Error 1
 pasadeveloper@ubuntu:~/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/qnx-armv7le-qcc$`

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you indicated what version of QNX you are trying to build for and what platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not "generate" your qmake-qnx like that. You are supposed to use the native qmake for generating proper makefiles for your target to aid the cross-compilation. Also, running `qmake qmake.conf` in the relevant mkspecs folder is wrong because that is not a project file as you may think.

When building Qt itself for instance, you should be using the proper mkspecs files for the target in which case, it is the one you also mentioned above if it is built for that particular arm qnx variant, called `qnx-armv7le-qcc`.

Here is the exact command you need to run after downloading the relevant Qt sources, like 5.1.1:

```
./configure -opensource -confirm-license -xplatform qnx-armv7le-qcc -v
```

For this QNX version, the bottom line is, if you do not have SP1 *and* libscreen, it will not work. The QPA plugin would link against it. This library provides the API to the graphics server on newer QNX variants. You need to talk to your QNX representatives.

[Here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QNX) you can find further information about the topic.

Answer (score 1):

> $QNX_TARGET=/opt/qnx650/target/qnx6

is probably not doing what you want.  In shell scripts, you don't put a "$" in front of a variable when you are defining the variable, only when you access the variable:

X=hello

echo $X